# Find all rows based on a cell value and copy to different sheet.

Tags: excel, vba, search

I am a excel/vba noob.  I have very little experience with vba.  I am not asking for someone to do my work for me just help me with some samples so I can start figuring out what I need.

I have been looking for a way to help me search a spread sheet based on a value I place in a cell.   Here is what I have.   I have a spread sheet that has 4 tabs, the first 3 tabs have different data and different number of columns.  The one thing that is the same on each table is the first three columns.

```
date         case#       ticket#
7/14/2018   50807966    5330826969
7/3/2018    50811017    5330860547
7/1/2018    50811022    5330860631
7/13/2018   50811026    5330860683
```

What I want to do is on sheet 4  enter a number in a cell labeled ticket# and find all rows on each sheet and copy it to the 4th sheet.   I want it to copy each row found to the next empty row on sheet 4.  I will start with sheet one and work through sheet 3.

What I would like help on is how to do the first sheet.  Once I have an Idea of how to do one sheet I can figure out how to do the rest.

Comment: Does the ticket number actually show up multiple times on the same sheet?  or just across all 3 sheets?  Since the 3 sheets have different columns, how are you going to organize the data on the 4th sheet?  Are they going to have set columns, or are you just going to copy whatever is there (and not have column headers)?

Comment: The ticket number can be on the same sheet multiple times.   Since each sheets has a different amount of columns, I will modify the answer I receive, for each sheet.  Eventually  I will put  the results from each sheet to a different section on sheet 4.  I think I can figure that out from the answers I receive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not clear what your 4th sheet looks like. This will look for a ticket number on your 4th sheet in cell A1.

Once executed, it will loop through each sheet and filter/copy/paste the first 4 columns for all values in filter.

You will need to change `.Sheets("Sheet4")` to match your sheet: `.Sheets("?")`

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro1()
Dim Ws As Worksheet, MyWs As Worksheet
Dim wsLRow As Long, MyLRow As Long

Set MyWs = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet4")

Dim TicketNumber As String
TicketNumber = MyWs.Range("A1")

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each Ws In Worksheets
    If Ws.Name <> MyWs.Name Then
        With Ws
            If .AutoFilterMode Then .AutoFilterMode = False
            wsLRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            MyLRow = MyWs.Range("A" & MyWs.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
            .Range("A:A").AutoFilter 1, TicketNumber
            .Range("A2:D" & wsLRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
            MyWs.Range("A" & MyLRow).PasteSpecial
            .AutoFilterMode = False
        End With
    End If
Next Ws
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

---

If will need to handle the error when your filter does not find anything.